# Error encountered when using Pip3.6 to install PyInstaller

Tags: python, compiler-errors, py2exe, pyinstaller, python-3.6

My goal is to create a standalone executable of a Python script for distribution. The file is a single Python script with multiple library imports in the code. I use Python 3.6.

I have yet to successfully use py2exe, but I was informed pyinstaller was necessary because py2exe does not handle everything. However, pyinstaller was only compatible with Python 2.x, but you could use pip3 to install on Python 3.x.

I ran the following:

> pip3.6 install pyinstaller

and received the stack trace below. PIP shows the library was installed, but trying to execute pyinstaller or import it fails. How would I move forward? Is there a better solution to allow someone to run a Python script without a Python install?

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 21
5, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", li
ne 317, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 74
2, in install
    **kwargs
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", lin
e 831, in install
    self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", lin
e 1032, in move_wheel_files
    isolated=self.isolated,
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\wheel.py", line 493, in
move_wheel_files
    maker.make_multiple(['%s = %s' % kv for kv in console.items()])
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\distlib\scripts.
py", line 383, in make_multiple
    filenames.extend(self.make(specification, options))
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\distlib\scripts.
py", line 372, in make
    self._make_script(entry, filenames, options=options)
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\distlib\scripts.
py", line 276, in _make_script
    self._write_script(scriptnames, shebang, script, filenames, ext)
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\distlib\scripts.
py", line 212, in _write_script
    launcher = self._get_launcher('t')
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\distlib\scripts.
py", line 351, in _get_launcher
    result = finder(distlib_package).find(name).bytes
  File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\distlib\resource
s.py", line 324, in finder
    raise DistlibException('Unable to locate finder for %r' % package)
pip._vendor.distlib.DistlibException: Unable to locate finder for 'pip._vendor.d
istlib'
```

Comment: I'm not certain that pyinstaller supports Python 3.6 yet? Could you roll back to 3.5?

Comment: A request has been submitted on the Pyinstaller GIT for 3.6 to be supported... https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/2331

Comment: If it is too soon since Python 3.6 has been released for pyinstaller support, I don't mind waiting. I am using Python 3.6 exclusive code such as f literals. I am new to using Python so I was surprised to see all the issues caused by upgrades breaking functioning code between modules and other drivers.

Comment: What error do you get when trying to execure pyinstaller?

Comment: @DanWheeler ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyinstaller' -- 3.6 was recently released. There isn't a resolution here until pyinstaller is updated. pip 9.0.1 also doesn't work on Python 3.6 IIRC.